# How to mimic a pressing ENTER on a TextField in Flutter Tests

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-test

Given that `tester.enterText` will allow me to enter the text on a `TextField` in a flutter test, how would I mock pressing the **DONE** key on the android keyboard or pressing **ENTER** on my keyboard inside the textfield?

This would also be equivalent to checking for the pressing of the **DONE** button on the IOS/android keyboard

Comment: Accept your own answer as the answer to this question :)
It helped me a lot

Answer (score 57):

I found the implementation in the flutter repo tests @ https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/7e445a17324ee7e615ef2c886d0cb9407853f338/packages/flutter/test/widgets/editable_text_test.dart#L558:

ex: `await tester.testTextInput.receiveAction(TextInputAction.done);`

```
// example
await tester.enterText(find.byKey(new Key('txtFieldKey')), 'Hello World!');
await tester.testTextInput.receiveAction(TextInputAction.done);
await tester.pump();
```

Comment: this obviously works for this, but for integration tests this wont work theres an open issue for this here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9383

Comment: @xpeldev Still, there is no solution for this in integration tests :(

Comment: With integration_test package this implementation works.

Comment: Great work. This helped ..

Comment: @xpeldev How to simulate keyboard action to clear text from TextField()?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70893913/flutter-integration-test-how-to-simulate-keyboard-action-to-clear-text-from-tex

Comment: Worked like charm!