# Flutter integration_test: How to simulate keyboard action to clear text from TextField()?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-web, flutter-integration-test

Implementing some integration_test for flutter-web application wherein I'm trying to simulate keyboard action to clear the content of the TextField(). Like we have for "Done" like:
`await tester.testTextInput.receiveAction(TextInputAction.done);`

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate keyboard presses in your test like this:

```dart
await simulateKeyDownEvent(LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace);
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/simulateKeyDownEvent.html

Comment: .Tried with the sample hello world counter application to clear the initial text from TextFormField but "await tester.sendKeyDownEvent(LogicalKeyboardKey.backspace);" seems to have no effect.
Raised issue in official repo....incase i am doing anything wrong let me know.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/97502

Comment: @RajeshPatil To be clear, I said `simulateKeyDownEvent` not `tester.sendKeyDownEvent`

Comment: no effect still the same result...fails with the same error(means one was found but none were expected)....but i suspect if i refer to the internal implementation its says platforms (e.g. Windows, iOS) are not yet supported.